# The notification icon appears differently in release mode than in debug

Tags: android, flutter, icons, flutter-local-notification

I did all the operations and procedures in the application and set the icon and it works normally in Debug. Not once. In release mode did not appear properly

He was working normally at Debug.
Not once.
Reales did not appear properly

Comment: Wanna share your project structure?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.